# Return prematurely from function in Racket

Tags: function, return, racket

How do I return from a function before reaching the last form in standard Racket? That can be useful to avoid another level of indentation and form nesting.

In Common Lisp there is [return](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_return.htm#return), a specialized form of return-from. Any equivalent in Racket, at least for return only?

Answer (score 10):

Use `let/ec` to create an escape continuation.

Example:

```
(let/ec return
  (for ([x 10000])
    (when (= x 100)
        (return x))))
```

Using let/ec is cheaper than using call/cc which creates a full continuation.